# /execute questions

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So, I got this genius idea to make a crafting table with custom recipes work anywhere, (If you just have /testforblocks running, it would only work at 1 location) using `/execute`.

My command would look like this:

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ testforblocks ~1 ~ ~ ~1 ~ ~ [Dispenser table coordinates]
```

But how would I tell it to

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ clone [Dispenser table Coordinates] ~1 ~ ~ ~1 ~ ~
```

but only to the people that match the /testforblocks?

Answer (score 3):

Set up a dummy objective, which we'll make store whether or not a player successfully tested for the dispenser:

```
/scoreboard objectives add FoundDispenser dummy
```

When a new player joins (or just on a clock) make the new player (or everyone) set their `SuccessCount` to store in their dummy score (FoundDispenser in this example), and nudge the dummy score off of Null:

```
execute @a ~ ~ ~ stats entity @p set SuccessCount @p FoundDispenser
scoreboard players add @a FoundDispenser 0
```

Run the execute testforblocks command, then run the execute clone command straight afterwards:

```
execute @a ~ ~ ~ testforblocks ~1 ~ ~ ~1 ~ ~ [Template Coordinates]
execute @a[score_FoundDispenser_min=1] ~ ~ ~ clone [Template Coordinates] ~1 ~ ~ ~1 ~ ~
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Ill try it out and make a note if anything doesn't work. *Tries out commands*

Comment: Wait, would this only work for 1 recipie for each scoreboard?